# Can you fade in (animate) sections of an R markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way to make each section of an R Markdown document load only once the user has reached it?

I ask because I am using Highcharter, and when charts load they have an animation. Those animations happen on the page load, and therefore the user does not see it as every section loads simulatenously.

I presume this is something to do with creating a custom CSS? I basically want the section to load once the user has scrolled to it.

Below is a reproducible example of where I have got to so far. If you see tabset 2, the animation causes the chart to fade in, but as the element is already loaded, there is no animation on the chart (i.e. the lines reloading).

````
    ---
title: "Minimal example"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: true
---


```{r, echo = FALSE}
aniview::use_aniview()
```


```{css, echo=FALSE}
p {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-animation: fadein 10s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 10s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 10s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 10s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 10s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

```


# scatter example

```{r, results='asis'}

x <- runif(10, 0, 10)
y <- runif(10, 0, 10)
data <- data.frame(x, y)
hc <- data %>% 
  hchart('scatter', hcaes(x = x, y = y))
hc

```

# line example

```{r, results='asis'}

x <- runif(10, 0, 10)
y <- runif(10, 0, 10)
data <- data.frame(x, y)
hc <- data %>% 
  hchart('line', hcaes(x = x, y = y))
hc

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

# Tabsets {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

## 1
```{r, results = 'asis'}
hc
```


## 2
::: {.aniview data-av-animation="slideInUp"}
```{r, results = 'asis'}
hc
```
:::

#  outside tabset


```{r, results = 'asis'}
x <- runif(10, 0, 10)
y <- runif(10, 0, 10)
data <- data.frame(x, y)
hc <- data %>% 
  hchart('scatter', hcaes(x = x, y = y))
hc
```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
````

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look into  *Scrollama Documents* in R that us JS. This is just a mock up to get the idea that the highlighted section only appears when the user scrolls to that section.

````
    ---
title: "Scrollama Document"
output: rolldown::scrollama
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.level1 {
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  padding: 1em 2em 2em;
}
.is-active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 80vh;
}
```


# Introduction



## Level-two heading

Level-two and below headings...

### Level-three

...are all contained in the same section.


# Text

Example text.


# Plots

You may include any number of plots in a section.

```{r}
par(mar = c(4, 4, .5, .1))
plot(cars, pch = 19)
plot(pressure, type = 'h')
```


# Images

Local news [reported](https://www.desmoinesregister.com/story/news/2018/04/27/rubber-duck-des-moines-yess-duck-derby/558852002/) a      giant     inflatable rubber duck rolling down the street of Des Moines, where this package is conceived.

![The Rolling Duck](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/163582/60457872-c164ff00-9c02-11e9-8d0f-cdae566b75ed.jpeg)


# Setup

You should call `rolldown::scrollama_setup()` at the end of a document. Turn off the `debug` option to get rid of the horizontal        line on     the page, and you probably also want `echo=FALSE` on this code chunk:

```{r}
rolldown::scrollama_setup(
  list(step = '.level1', offset = .2, debug = TRUE)
)
```
````